# Stop and Restart ASP.NET Timer

Tags: asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET Timer control on my web page.

The timer is used as a trigger for an `UpdatePanel`. Once the content of this panel is loaded, I disable the Timer using `Timer.Enabled = false;` in the code. This disables the Timer from firing the Tick event.

I want to restart this timer if the user wishes to re-run the code on a button click. However, if I use `Timer.Enabled = true;` in the button click event, it only enables the timer when the page postsback. Evidently, this is not the behaviour I would like.

I tried to do the same using javascript,

```
var timer = $find('<%=TimerAH.ClientID %>');
timer._startTimer();
//timer.set_enabled(true);
```

This code also does not help. I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have these many client site functions for ASP.NET timer that you can easily use.

But be careful that Javascript function which start with **underscore** are **private fucnctions by convention**. They can be changed by the author, but i guess its safe to use as Microsoft is know to be good in providing backward compatibility.

[Controlling the ASP.NET Timer Control with JavaScript](http://disturbedbuddha.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/controlling-the-aspnet-timer-control-with-javascript/)

```
    var timer = $find(‘<%= Timer1.ClientID %>’);

    //returns the timer’s interval in milliseconds: 
    var waitTime = timer.get_interval;       

    //sets the timer’s interval to 5000 milliseconds (or 5 seconds): 
    timer.set_interval(5000);       

    //returns whether or not the timer is enabled: 
    var isTimerEnabled = timer.get_enabled();       

    //disables the timer: 
    timer.set_enabled(false);       

    //starts the timer: 
    timer._startTimer();       

    //stops the timer: 
    timer._stopTimer();
```

Comment: I am aware of the information you have provided, but as I mentioned, I tried using this method to start the timer. However, the timer event in the code behind does not fire until the page postsback.

Comment: @SoulSlayer I suggest you try this. Dont disable/enable the timer in server side. Just use the client side functions. This is just a guess, May be once you disable the timer in server side you can not enable it from client side.