# Get ASP.NET Ajax Timer status via Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, timer

I have an ASP.NET Ajax Timer which I can stop or start using the following jQuery/Javascript:

```
var timer = $("[id$=Timer1]");
timer[0].control._stopTimer();

...

timer[0].control._startTimer();
```

How can I get the timer's current started/stopped status? The requirement is via Javascript/jQuery not code behind (VB/C#).

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391663/stop-and-restart-asp-net-timer) where it mentions the "enable" property, but I understand that "stopping/starting" is distinct than "enabling/disabling" for a timer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way so I'll post the answer to be helpful to others. Get the "_timer" attribute:

```
var status = timer[0].control._timer;
alert(status);
```

When timer is on its "_start" status it will return an integer.
When timer is on its "_stop" status it will return 'null'.